# Where is the mistake in my solution? Trigonometry proof

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

> To prove: $$1 + 2 \sin 70^\circ = \frac{1}{2\sin 20^\circ}$$

My attempt:
$$\begin{align}
1 + 2 \sin 70^\circ &= 1 + \frac{\sin 140^\circ}{\cos 70^\circ} \\[6pt]
&= 1 + \frac{\sin 40^\circ}{\sin 20^\circ} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\sin 20^\circ + \sin 40^\circ}{\sin 20^\circ} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{2\sin 30^\circ \cos 10^\circ}{\sin 20^\circ} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\cos 10^\circ}{2\sin 10^\circ \cos 10^\circ} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2\sin 10^\circ} \\
\end{align}$$

Can anyone explain where my mistake is?

[(original solution image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3wph.png)

Comment: Where's your proof?

Comment: Perhaps the mistake isn't yours:$$1+2\sin 70^\circ = 2.879\dots \qquad \frac{1}{2\sin 20^\circ} =1.461\dots \qquad \frac{1}{2\sin 10^\circ} = 2.879\dots$$

Comment: I TeX-ified your solution, fixing a typo (missing "sin"). Please double-check my work.

Comment: You have forget the factor $2\sin 30\circ$ in the 5th line. You must end with    $\frac{\sin 30\circ}{\sin 10\circ}$ instead of $\frac {1}{2\sin 10\circ}$

Comment: @Piquito: $\sin 30^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$. :)

Comment: Oh my God! Then you have no mistake in your deduction, I guess. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments:

- The original identity is wrong (LHS $\approx 2.88$, RHS $\approx 1.46$).
- Your derivation of $1 + 2 \sin 70^\circ =  \dfrac{1}{2\sin 10^\circ}$is correct.